# How Github hide email from spam bots

Tags: javascript, html, email, github

I can see following code in Github Profile page

```
 <a 
     class="email js-obfuscate-email" 
     data-email="%66%69%7a%65%72%6b%68%61%6e%40%67%6d%61%69%6c%2e%63%6f%6d" 
     href="mailto:{email}">
       {email}
 </a>
```

How it works?

Comment: @runtime the href template gets replaced by the "encrypted" data-email attribute.

Comment: what kind of encryption. Can you share some code how they did it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of data-email is just the hexadecimal version of your email address "fizerkhan@gmail.com".

It is a sequence of hexadecimal characters, where each character is of the form %XY, where X and Y are hexadecimal digits (0-f). For example, the first two hexadecimal characters in your case are %66 and %69. If you look at the ASCII table (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), the symbol that corresponds to ASCII with hexadecimal number 66 is "f", while for hexadecimal number 69 is "i".

You can use play around with this tool http://www.asciitohex.com/.

Comment: If they get `data-email` by jquery after rendering, then how do they place `{email}` entry?